# What exactly is a target in the context of ROS, catkin and workspaces?

Tags: ros, catkin, ros-kinetic, documentation, cmake

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have seen the word "target" used in different articles, but I have not seen a clear definition of it. For example, this article http://wiki.ros.org/eros/Tutorials/Install%20Targets is about installing targets. In this question https://answers.ros.org/question/217475/cmakeliststxt-vs-packagexml/?answer=217488#post-id-217488, the author states

> CMakeLists.txt is a build script, it does not explicitly express the run dependencies of the targets that get built

I have seen so many places using the word "target" in the context of ROS and catkin, but the uses do not always seem consistent. I suppose this has something to do with `make` and `cmake`, but I am not very familiar with these tools. So, could you please explain to me what a target, in the context of ROS, catkin and workspaces, is?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/286122/what-exactly-is-a-target-in-the-context-of-ros,-catkin-and-workspaces?/) by [nbro](https://answers.ros.org/users/29569/nbro/) on ROS Answers with karma: 372 on 2018-03-21

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> I suppose this has something to do with `make` and `cmake`, but I am not very familiar with these tools. So, could you please explain to me what a target, in the context of ROS, catkin and workspaces, is?

That would be difficult (without knowledge of the buildtools that you refer to), as it in most cases is the same concept as in `make` and `cmake` or very closely related to it.

I would suggest to review fi [wikipedia/Makefile - Contents](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Makefile#Contents) and perhaps [OSDev/Makefile](https://wiki.osdev.org/Makefile#Basics).

---

Edit: there is also CMake's documentation: [cmake-buildsystem(7)](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/manual/cmake-buildsystem.7.html). This may be a bit technical though.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-03-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [nbro](https://answers.ros.org/users/29569/nbro/) on 2018-03-22**:
I hadn't accepted your answer and it today it turned out to be accepted. What the heck is going on?

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2018-03-22**:
When the user has a history of not accepting answers moderators will sometimes accept an answer that appears to be correct. Note moderators cannot accept their own answers and there is a period of time where only you can accept an answer. However, I'm not sure why you wouldn't accept this answer...

**Comment by [nbro](https://answers.ros.org/users/29569/nbro/) on 2018-03-22**:
@William. I am not satisfied with this answer yet, that's why I don't accept it.

**Comment by [nbro](https://answers.ros.org/users/29569/nbro/) on 2018-03-22**:
So, what are (the usual) targets in ROS? Examples of targets? Are packages targets? I more or less understand what a target in the context of `make` is. In my question I also say that the term "target" seems to be used to signify different things or, at least, people seem to abuse of its usage.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-03-22**:\

> What the heck is going on?

I wouldn't know. I certainly didn't accept it for you.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-03-22**:
And an observation: re: "what the heck" and "why on earth": this may be your normal way of expressing yourself, but I must say that for me *personally* it comes across as antagonistic and unnecessarily strong.

These are good questions, but your phrasing seems to imply that you're feeling very ..

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-03-22**:
.. strongly about the subjects raised and can't see any reasonable explanation for why they are in their current state or why they are there in the first place.

That may not be the best way to approach a community forum.